# bootstrap 4 validation icons repeat all through the input width with prestshop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, twitter-bootstrap-4, prestashop-1.7

I'm creating a prestashop 1.7.2.1 module. Prestashop comes with bootstrap 4 support.

I'm trying to use the from validation example from https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#validation with the following code:

```
 <div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row has-success">
      <label for="inputHorizontalSuccess" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputHorizontalSuccess" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <div class="form-control-feedback">Success! You've done it.</div>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row has-warning">
      <label for="inputHorizontalWarning" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-warning" id="inputHorizontalWarning" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <div class="form-control-feedback">Shucks, check the formatting of that and try again.</div>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row has-danger">
      <label for="inputHorizontalDnger" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputHorizontalDnger" placeholder="name@example.com">
        <div class="form-control-feedback">Sorry, that username's taken. Try another?</div>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">Example help text that remains unchanged.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

using `Pingendo 4` (bootstrap 4 desktop app editor) it works properly.
but when I add this code to my prestashop module all the inputs contains the validation icons repeated all through the input's width.

[image: form validation example]

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrestaShop's bootstrap CSS for these icons is being overriden by PrestaShop's own CSS.

[image: PrestaShop CSS]

When disabling the background property, it works fine.

[image: Disabled property]

You can modify the CSS and change `background` property to `background-color`.

Comment: I needed add the folowing to .form-control class: background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right; thanks!